# I am an American citizen but have never lived in the US. Do I need to fill a W8-BEN or a W-9?

Tags: united-states, income-tax

I have a dual citizenship (US and non-US), and I have never lived in the US, nor have I worked in the US, except for 4 non-consecutive months as a counselor in a summer camp.

I work in a multi-national corporation (based in the US), and my stock options are managed in the US.  The investment bank there is asking all employees to file a W8-BEN or a W-9.

Am I required to file a W8-BEN or a W-9?  On the one hand, I am a US citizen, on the other hand, I don't live or work in the US.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you do.  You also need to file a tax return every year, and if you have more than $50k of total savings [you need to declare this every year](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/5557/as-a-us-citizen-should-i-only-have-50-000-in-non-us-banks-due-to-fatca).

Answer (score 0):

Your employer can require a W8-BEN or W-9 if you are a contractor, and in some special cases.  I believe this bank managing your stock options can as well; it's to prove you don't have "foreign status".  See [the IRS's W-9 instructions](http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/iw9.pdf) for details.