# What are some legitimate places to buy gold bullion bars in USA?

Tags: united-states, investing, gold, bullion

I am looking to buy gold bars. Just the element with minimal "craftsmanship". What are some good places/outlets to buy gold in the USA?

Comment: You want to hold the real thing, why ? Other than being robbed why take the undue risk of holding something valuable. Why not buy into gold ETFs. Same thing only somebody else takes the risk of protecting it.

Comment: Note that a **"standard" gold bar** weighs **400 troy ounces**. Gold value is (now) about **$1360** per troy ounce.  So: One standard gold bar is worth about **$544,000.** Is a standard bar what you're looking for, or perhaps something more .. *accessible*, like low-weight *gold coins, wafers, or non-standard bars?*  ;-)

Comment: @Chris W.Rea Thanks for the clarification! Not lookin gfor the "standard" ... but accessible ones..without the craftsmanship paraphrenelia ..as in coins.

Comment: You many want to check out this question: (http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/5559/buying-gold-silver-as-a-hedge-against-hyperinflation).

Answer (score 1):

http://www.kitco.com and http://www.goldmoney.com are a couple.

Answer (score 1):

Kitco, Blanchard, Apmex, Monex, etc.  You can also find plenty of offerings on eBay, and if you know what you're doing (small bars), that's probably not a completely crazy way to buy or sell.