# Ideas about Gold Investment

Tags: gold

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Pros & cons of buying gold directly vs. investing in a gold ETF like GLD, IAU, SGOL?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/18231/pros-cons-of-buying-gold-directly-vs-investing-in-a-gold-etf-like-gld-iau-s)

I’m a new player in this so I hope someone can offer me some suggestions.

I want to invest in gold, maybe buy a small lot of gold coins or bullion. But I’m also thinking of starting a portfolio with gold ETF.

Which would be a better option and why?

Comment: Since any answer i could provide would be non-exhaustive, the most i can contribute is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gold_exchange-traded_product, which is a very good compilation of exchange traded (paper) gold.

Comment: Please, don't invest in something just because you have a feeling (or your neighbor/uncle/buddy told you) that it's the next hot thing. It isn't

Comment: @Charlie - what reasons do you have for wishing to buy gold? And in what dollar amounts are you looking to invest? Your answers would impact the advice you'll get here.

Comment: Charlie, thanks for your edit - I've re-opened the question.  Yet, we're still lacking your **country** and some idea about your investment goals.  These will impact any answer.  Thank you.

Comment: Without more detail, I agree this is now a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Physical gold fees/risks: low liquidity, high transaction costs, storage costs, security risk

ETFs risks: futures basis, ETF solvency, ETF implied costs
Gold Futures risks: basis, margin

Risks that apply to both physical/financial metal holdings: economic slowdowns, general market volatilities, opportunity costs, under performance against actual rate of inflation, and etc.